# Assembly-Tasm string input without buffer size and length

Tags: string, assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I want to make string input, but not like 0Ah interrupt method. This method adds 2 values before the inputed string, buffer size and string length. Is there other interrupt that I can only input string without this values?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a string with DOS function [3Fh - READ FROM FILE OR DEVICE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2783.htm).

```
MOV AH,3Fh          ; DOS function number.
MOV BX,0            ; File handle of standard input (keyboard).
MOV CX,SizeOfBuffer ; Maximal number of bytes to read.
LEA DX,[Buffer]     ; Offset of memory reserved for the string.
INT 21h             ; Invokation of DOS function.
JC Error
```